# How to recreate the conflicted file state with the checkout command?

Tags: git, merge

I have long life branch and some time ago I have resolved big merge conflict. Now I want again merge `master` into my branch but got conflict. I have google a bit and found [`rerere`](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)  feature.

But when I do:

```
git checkout --conflict=merge FileTheMergeConflictWas.ext
```

I get nothing.

What should I do to create merge conflict resolution file and complete my current merge with automatic resolution?

Comment: How would like the merge to resolve?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `using previous resolution` I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your merge is already committed, it is in one sense too late.  The rerere code works by recording the conflict *at the time the conflict occurs*, and then recording (separately) the conflict *resolution* once you have resolved the conflict.

Both the conflict itself, and your previous resolution, happened in the past, when `git rerere` was not enabled.  Hence, to get `git rerere` to record them now, you must go back in time, enable `git rerere`, start the merge, *get* the conflict, *resolve* the conflict, and then return to the present.

If you have a time machine handy, you can use that. :-)  Most of us don't, but fortunately, Git *is* a time machine!  Well, sort of.

Simply turn on `git rerere`, then check out the correct commit using the history.  This will give you a "detached HEAD" with `HEAD` pointing to the commit that you just checked out.  Which commit is the correct one?  Well, the one right before you did the merge last time, of course.  That's the *first parent* of the existing merge commit.

Then, now that you have a detached HEAD and are on the correct commit, do the merge, which will have conflicts:

```
git merge <hash-id>
```

What's the correct hash ID for the commit to merge?  Why, the one you used when you did the merge last time, of course.  That's the *second parent* of the existing merge commit.

This merge will, of course, fail due to the conflict.  But now the conflict is recorded, because you, back in the past with your detached HEAD, are recording this time.  Now resolve the conflict the same way you did before.  To save time, you can simply copy the correct resolution from the past.  That correct resolution is *in the merge you committed*.  So:

```
git show <merge-id>:path/to/conflict.ext > path/to/conflict.ext
```

Now `git add` the resolved file (repeat for all files as needed) and run `git commit` to record the final resolution.

Now, time-travel back to the present, abandoning the merge you just made.  It has served its purpose, which was to record the conflict and the resolution:

```
git checkout thebranch
```

and you are now ready to go.

#### Minor annoyances

If you are currently in the middle of a conflicted merge or rebase, you will have to abort it now, then use the Git time machine to go back and re-merge, then restart your conflicted merge or rebase.  (If you have a lot of useful work done, you might want to save it first—just commit it somewhere and/or create a branch or tag name pointing to the current commit, as needed and appropriate—and only *then* abort.)

Comment: It seems option like `--from` is missed: `git checkout --conflict=merge --from <merge-id> FileTheMergeConflictWas.ext`. So `git` do all you have just described automatically.

Comment: You don't want `git checkout --conflict` as that does a merge into your *current* (index) state.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to **torek**. I complete next steps while I am on my branch:

```
git log --merges --oneline

30275e6 Merge branch 'master' into feature/5521_sign_cart_items
c28e258 Merge branch 'master' into feature/5521_sign_cart_items
f01e32c Merge branch 'master' into 5452_promocode
```

Take  from first line `30275e6`:

```
$ git show 30275e6
commit 30275e60ae49f0139d8a0537dd8dc215b7fa2908
Merge: e8d66f0 81249af
Author: Eugen Konkov <>
Date:   Tue Oct 25 19:57:16 2016 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' into feature/5521_sign_cart_items
```

We need this info: `Merge: e8d66f0 81249af`. The `e8d66f0` is last commit on our branch before we `master` master. `81249af` is last commit on master at that time. Look which state were at that time:

```
* b915f22 Code cleanup
*   30275e6 Merge branch 'master' into feature/5521_sign_cart_items
|\  
| * 81249af 5663 fixed
| * c4f02ae 5452 fixed
* | e8d66f0 Code cleanup
```

Now I should use time machine (thank you **torek**):

```
git checkout e8d66f0 # We are at detached head now
git merge 81249af
```

Here I got conflict. Now I should resolve as I did before. This is the result of my merge `30275e6`

```
git checkout 30275e6 FileTheMergeConflictWas.ext
git commit
```

After this I switch back into my branch and merge `master`

```
git checkout my_branch
git merge master
```

Saved resolution will be used. Good luck ;-)